# How to put stories into "length" categories based on wordcount?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a story database in MS Access 2010. One of the entry fields is word count (in thousands). I want my database to automatically put each story in a "length" category (short/long/etc) based on the word count, and I want the categories to be adjustable.

Irritatingly, this is almost exactly the same as classifying numerical grades into A/B/C/etc, yet I can't find an answer anywhere. I *think* it needs some sort of BETWEEN query.

The relevant tables and fields are

```
tblStories
StoryID ...author, title... WordCount
1                           0,7
2                           21
3                           9
...

tblLength
LengthID    Length   Min  Max
1           Flash    0    0,7
2           Short    0,8  8
3           Long     9    18
4           Novella  19   50
5           Novel    50
```

[Note: WordCount has one decimal place when <1, and is an integer else, so intermediate values aren't a problem.]

---

I want the database to know that Story 1 is Flash, Story 2 is Novella, and Story 3 is Long.

I also want to be able to change my (somewhat arbitrary) word boundaries in tblLength and have the story length class change accordingly; for instance, if I decide 9k is now the maximum for "short", then the database should identify Story 3 as Short.

On the form, you can either:

- Enter the word count (e.g. 6k), or
- Select the length category ("Short")

Word count overrides any previously entered category, and locks the control.

Disclaimer: I've the feeling the answer to this must be very obvious, but I'm very much learning this stuff as I go along - I can faff around with forms and subs a bit now, but this is my first query. Apologies for noobishness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL apparently doesn't like BETWEEN in a JOIN clause, but this seems to work:

[tblStories]

```
StoryID  WordCount
-------  ---------
      1        0.7
      2         21
      3          9
```

[tblLength]

```
LengthID  Length   WordCountMin  WordCountMax
--------  -------  ------------  ------------
       1  Flash               0           0.7
       2  Short             0.8             8
       3  Long                9            18
       4  Novella            19            50
       5  Novel              51    9999999999
```

The query

```sql
SELECT tblStories.StoryID, tblStories.WordCount, tblLength.Length
FROM
    tblStories
    INNER JOIN
    tblLength
        ON tblStories.WordCount >= tblLength.WordCountMin 
            AND tblStories.WordCount <= tblLength.WordCountMax
```

returns

```
StoryID  WordCount  Length 
-------  ---------  -------
      1        0.7  Flash  
      2         21  Novella
      3          9  Long
```

and if I simply edit the data in [tblLength] to

```
      2  Short             0.8             9
      3  Long               10            18
```

and run the same query again I get

```
StoryID  WordCount  Length 
-------  ---------  -------
      1        0.7  Flash  
      2         21  Novella
      3          9  Short
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. 

I'm sorry it took so long for me to reply; my laptop fried, which was a little distracting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM  
         tblStories s INNER JOIN 
         tblLength l ON s.WordCount BETWEEN l.min AND l.max
```